# How can I enable gzip compression on youtube iframe API using Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, gzip, youtube-iframe-api

When I run my page on gtmatrix we get the following result:

[GTmetrix results](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/translate.video/kBDjz01b)

Enable compression for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 146.9KiB (83% reduction).

Compressing https://translate.video/ could save 146.5KiB (84% reduction).
Compressing https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api could save 366B (43% reduction).

The thing is that we are not embedding any youtube video or iframe, so we don't know we're is this comming from.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: If you check in network tab of developer console, you can see that autoptimize plugin is initiator of youtube iframe_api. You may research around that plugin.